# Xamarin.Android check API Level

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I have an Android App that has been developed, compiled and released using the default SDK option

> Use Compile using SDK Version

I need to make additions to this application, however I do not know what SDK it targeted at compiled time when it was last tested and released.

The problem being later API levels have different requirements, such as Authorization changes where you need to seek permission from the user. I can see from the code this does not do this, so it must be earlier.

Is there a way to know from source or the previous compiled .apk which SDK was used? I do not have permission to update all of the code to add in all of these authorization changes, just have a few small changes to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `.apk` is just a zip file, so unzip it and look at the manifest xml file.

Near the top of the file you should find an element that **can** contain the min, target and max SDK.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

You will be looking for the `targetSdkVersion` API level

re: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Looks like in the compiled apk the AndroidManifest.xml file isn't xml. I just get lots of ascii characters. I can see in source though that only `android:minSdkVersion` was set. Might just need to do a bit of trial and error

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can add your changes inside an if like this:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.**TheVersionYouNeed**) {
   // Your code
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. If I compile against the wrong SDK, for example Android API 23 I would need to retrofit all the checks to request permissions from users for each component the app uses. I cannot do that. I need to compile against the correct API used by previous developer